# Django Elastic Beanstalk Implementing Cron job

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron

I am trying to set a cron job on my project to send a email after 15 minutes.

```
04_cronjb:
    command: "* * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py cronjb"
    leader_only: true
```

This is what i am using in config file

But when i try to deploy my project it shows a weird error

```
 Command failed on instance. Return code: 127 Output: /bin/sh: __init__.py: command not found.
```

**init**.py is the file which is in root of my folder.
When i try the simple command

```
04_cronjb:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py cronjb"
    leader_only: true
```

It works fine.
What am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: Looks you are not using cron configuration file. So you just trying to execute the command with wildcards. Did you check this document? https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: I have now created cron-linux.config file ```files:
    "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            

            * * * * * source /opt/python/current/env && python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py cronjb``` So now how to mention this in django.config